# Forcing the build to fail if there is a .net version mismatch

Tags: c#, msbuild, build, nant

We have a few apps that still have to be 2.0 because they are going to go on client machines that won't have the v3.5 framework installed, and we want to make sure no code gets slipped in that doesn't belong.  I know the 3.5 framework includes the 2.0 framework.  That said, we're trying to make sure that if someone inadvertently changes the targeted version on a specific project from 2.0 to something else, our automated builds will fail.  This shouldn't happen, but we're trying to be extra careful.

We thought there might be someway using beforeBuild and possibly the TargetFrameworkVersion in the .csproj file.  As in "if the TargetFrameworkVersion is not 2.0, output message and fail the build".  Is this possible/the best way to do this?

Comment: .NET 3.5 is built on top of 2.0 - it uses the same runtime. What problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm going to rephrase the question a little bit; this wasn't as clear to me when I was asked to research it.  But we have *target* environments where 3.5 won't be installed, and apparently there's a worry that someone won't realize a given project needs to stay 2.0, and we want nightly/targeted builds to fail if it gets changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to change the "Target Framework" of the project(s) in question to .Net Framework 2.0.

From the MSDN article "If you change the .NET Framework version, you may receive error messages if your code contains references to a different version. "

Great MSDN walk-through here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

If you want to enforce version 2.0 on the build server, then modify the msbuild options to "override" the toolset version to 2.0. This command switch takes precedent over the project settings file, and "causes all projects and their project-to-project dependencies to be built according to that ToolsVersion, even if each project in the solution specifies its own". Here is the msdn on what a toolset is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383796(v=vs.90).aspx and here is the MSDN on how to specify the command line switch:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383985(v=vs.90).aspx

If you are using TFS to do your nightly builds then here is how to add the argument (i'm using VS 2010 Pro):

1. Go to Team Explorer and expand the project
2. Right click the builds item
3. Select New Build Definition (or edit an existing build definition)
4. Go to Process
5. Expand "Agent Settings"
6. Find MsBuild Arguments.
7. Add /tv:2.0 and save the build changes when you have finished with any other settings.

Now, even if the project file changes the build server will catch code above the 2.0 level and fail. If you are not using TFS to do the builds, see if your tool lets you modify the msbuild command line.

Comment: I know how to do that; I altered the question to make what I was after clearer.

Comment: If i understand your clarification correctly, you want any language features from version of .NET greater than 2.0 to not get into the build, then this solution will work. I added the quote from MSDN "If you change the .NET Framework version, you may receive error messages if your code contains references to a different version". I believe that means if i use a feature from .NEt 3.5 in a project targeting .NET 2.0 then i will receive an error. Is this what your after?

Comment: I'm still not making it clear enough, I think.  You are correct that we don't want >2.0 features making it into the build.  We also want to guard against, for example, a dev going in and changing the target framework to v3.5, as this application is going to be installed on machines that only have the 2.0 framework installed.  We want our automated builds to notify us of such chicanery.

Comment: Ok, i see what you mean. I have added more detail to my answer to address how to catch that situation on the build server.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation (sorry I missed it).  We're not using TFS to do nightly builds (I'm pretty sure we just schedule windows tasks to run our NANT scripts, but I'm going to check with someone).  Also, I can't add build definitions, so I'm assuming there's a permissions issue I need to speak to someone about.  This now sounds like what I would want to do but I can't test it yet.